# Errors including Inkscape pdf_tex file using TexPad

Tags: inkscape

I recently installed TexPad on my iPad Pro, so that I could edit my files on that device in addition to my computer.  The `.tex`-file I am trying to compile has figures in it which I drew in Inkscape, and I have used the `\include{}` command to add the `pdf_tex` file to `.tex`-file.  I get no errors on my computer, using LaTeX in TeXshop, but I get the following errors when trying to compile it using TexPad:

> "Package keyval Error: page undefined;"  "Xwalk.pdf.bb not found" (Xwalk is the name of the file I'm including); and "LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in Xwalk.pdf.bb (no BoundingBox)."

Here is a stripped down version of the file that shows the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, latexsym, nameref, 
enumerate} %mathtools
\usepackage{amsrefs} 
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,plotmarks}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\def\svgwidth{4in}  
\centering\input{Xwalk.pdf_tex} \\
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the content of my Xwalk.pdf_tex file:

```
  \begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but 
the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
 \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text 
in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
  \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
 \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
 \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
 \setlength{\unitlength}{456.73500977bp}%
 \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
   \relax%
 \else%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
 \fi%
 \else%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
 \fi%
 \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
\global\let\svgscale\undefined%
 \makeatother%
 \begin{picture}(1,0.26410091)%
  \put(0.95871715,0.19621295){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]
 {\smash{}}}%
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{Xwalk.pdf}}%
\put(0.12539791,0.15640471){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]
{\smash{$v(i_1)$ }}}%
\put(0.59296592,0.20554772){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]
{\smash{$v(i_3)$ }}}%
  \put(0.711906,0.2068285){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]
{\smash{$v(i_4)$ }}}%
\put(0.46907574,0.16702023){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]
{\smash{$\gamma$}}}%
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=2]{Xwalk.pdf}}%
\put(-0.00198847,0.13915447){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]
{\smash{$v(i_0)$ }}}%
\put(0.30586193,0.17630884){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]
{\smash{$v(i_2)$ }}}%
    \put(0.88838919,0.18957826){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]
{\smash{$v(i_5)$ }}}%
\end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

I have read other similar posts that suggest removing the lines that begin with `\put` and have `page=2` in them, but when I do this and compile the file on the computer with TeXshop, some of the content of the diagram is lost. I have also read other posts about needing to use `pdftex` or `latex` to include certain types of files, but (as far as I've found) TexPad doesn't give me an option of which of these to use to typeset the file.

EDIT: Here is the log file.  Unfortunately, I had to remove a few lines to fit the character requirements for the post -- I hope there is enough to help diagnose the problem.

```
 This is e-TeX, Version 3.1415926 (vvtex) (preloaded format=latex 2016.4.21)  10 MAY 2017 13:31
entering extended mode
**&latex sample.tex 
(sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
\linespacing=\dimen102
\normalparindent=\dimen103
\normaltopskip=\skip41
(/vvtpackfile/tex/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2016/03/03 v2.15a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip42
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(/vvtpackfile/tex/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen104
)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count79
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 199.
\uproot@=\count80
\leftroot@=\count81
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 297.
\classnum@=\count82
\DOTSCASE@=\count83
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 394.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 397.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 518.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 630.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 631.
\macc@depth=\count84
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count85
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count86
\dspbrk@lvl=\count87
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count88
\column@=\count89
\maxfields@=\count90
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip43
\multlinetaggap=\skip44
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2735.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2736.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 388.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert199
\abstractbox=\box28
\listisep=\skip45
\c@part=\count91
\c@section=\count92
\c@subsection=\count93
\c@subsubsection=\count94
\c@paragraph=\count95
\c@subparagraph=\count96
\c@figure=\count97
\c@table=\count98
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\captionindent=\dimen113
\thm@style=\toks19
\thm@bodyfont=\toks20
\thm@headfont=\toks21
\thm@notefont=\toks22
\thm@headpunct=\toks23
\thm@preskip=\skip48
\thm@postskip=\skip49
\thm@headsep=\skip50
\dth@everypar=\toks24
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/latexsym.sty
Package: latexsym 1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
\symlasy=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/lasy/m/n --> U/lasy/b/n on input line 52.
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
(/vvtpackfile/tex/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks25
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
))))
\c@section@level=\count99
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 353.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 353.
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks26
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/amsrefs.sty
Package: amsrefs 2013/03/07 v2.14
(/vvtpackfile/tex/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip11
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pcatcode.sty
Package: pcatcode 2002/04/16 v1.04
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/ifoption.sty
Package: ifoption 2002/03/04 v1.02
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/rkeyval.sty
Package: rkeyval 2004/05/05 v1.08
\@temptokenb=\toks27
\rsk@toks=\toks28
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/textcmds.sty
Package: textcmds 2012/08/02 v2.00
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/mathscinet.sty
Package: mathscinet 2002/04/17 v1.05
)
\c@bib=\count100
\@maxlabelwidth=\dimen114
\c@bib@env=\count101
\bib@dbfile=\read1
\alpha@suffix=\count102
\series@index=\count103
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/xspace.sty
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/a4wide.sty
Package: a4wide 1994/08/30
(/vvtpackfile/tex/a4.sty
Package: a4 2004/04/15 v1.2g A4 based page layout
)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2015/04/1 Graphics configuration of vvtex
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: vvtex.def on input line 95.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/vvtex.def
File: vvtex.def 2015/03/01 v1.0
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen115
\Gin@req@width=\dimen116
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
(/vvtpackfile/tex/hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `etexcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `kvsetkeys' (already loaded).
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: pdfTeX >= 1.30 not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is not available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is not available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `refcount' (already loaded).
Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen117
\Hy@linkcounter=\count104
\Hy@pagecounter=\count105
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count106
(/vvtpackfile/tex/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count107
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5041.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen118
\Fld@menulength=\count108
\Field@Width=\dimen119
\Fld@charsize=\dimen120
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6295.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6300.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6303.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6310.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6315.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6320.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6325.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6365.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6369.
\Hy@abspage=\count109
\c@Item=\count110
\c@Hfootnote=\count111
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/vvtpackfile/tex/hdvips.def
File: hdvips.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for dvips
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pdfmark.def
File: pdfmark.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
\pdf@docset=\toks29
\pdf@box=\box29
\pdf@toks=\toks30
\pdf@defaulttoks=\toks31
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count112
\Fld@listcount=\count113
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count114
(/vvtpackfile/tex/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: Feature \pdfmdfivesum is not available
(rerunfilecheck)             (e.g. pdfTeX or LuaTeX with package `pdftexcmds').
(rerunfilecheck)             Therefore file contents cannot be checked efficiently
(rerunfilecheck)             and the loading of the package is aborted.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip51
)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/color.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2015/09/1 Colour configuration of vvtex
)
Package xcolor Info: Package option `usenames' ignored on input line 216.
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: vvtex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 2015/12/30 v3.0k Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/tikz.sty (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgf.sty (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfrcs.sty (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks32
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen121
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen122
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box30
(/vvtpackfile/tex/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfcore.sty (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfsys.sty (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks33
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks34
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks35
))
\pgf@x=\dimen123
\pgf@y=\dimen124
\pgf@xa=\dimen125
\pgf@ya=\dimen126
\pgf@xb=\dimen127
\pgf@yb=\dimen128
\pgf@xc=\dimen129
\pgf@yc=\dimen130
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count115
\c@pgf@countb=\count116
\c@pgf@countc=\count117
\c@pgf@countd=\count118
\t@pgf@toka=\toks36
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks37
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks38
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-vvtex.def
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfsys-vvtex.def)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count119
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count120
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmath.code.tex (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen131
\pgfmath@count=\count121
\pgfmath@box=\box31
\pgfmath@toks=\toks39
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks40
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks41
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count122
)) (/vvtpackfile/tex/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
```

[Text removed due to character restrictions]

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 1277.
Package scrextend Info: unexpected definition of `\@makefnmark'.
(scrextend)             Trying to patch it on input line 1391.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count136
)
Package scrextend Info: patch seems to be successfull on input line 1391.
) (/vvtpackfile/tex/blindtext.sty
Package: blindtext 2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
\c@blindtext=\count137
\c@Blindtext=\count138
\c@blind@countparstart=\count139
\blind@countxx=\count140
\blindtext@numBlindtext=\count141
\blind@countyy=\count142
\c@blindlist=\count143
\c@blindlistlevel=\count144
\c@blindlist@level=\count145
\blind@listitem=\count146
\c@blind@listcount=\count147
\c@blind@levelcount=\count148
\blind@mathformula=\count149
\blind@Mathformula=\count150
\c@blind@randomcount=\count151
\c@blind@randommax=\count152
\c@blind@pangramcount=\count153
\c@blind@pangrammax=\count154
) (sample.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 23.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 23.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+lasy on input line 23.
(/vvtpackfile/tex/ulasy.fd
File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box44
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 23.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 23.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 23.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 23.
(sample.out) (sample.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (Xwalk.pdf_tex

! Package keyval Error: page undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.53 ...hics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{Xwalk.pdf}}
                                                  %
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

File: Xwalk.pdf Graphic file (type vvtimg)
<Xwalk.pdf>

! Package keyval Error: page undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.58 ...hics[width=\unitlength,page=2]{Xwalk.pdf}}
                                                  %
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

File: Xwalk.pdf Graphic file (type vvtimg)
<Xwalk.pdf>) [1]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 31.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 31.
(sample.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 31.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 31.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 31.
 )
```

Comment: Can you add the `.log` file?

Comment: Just as a test, does your document compile if you comment out the two lines with `\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{Xwalk.pdf}}%` and `\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=2]{Xwalk.pdf}}%`?

Comment: @samcarter  Yes, it does compile if I comment out those two lines (both on the computer and on the iPad), but parts of the diagram are missing on both.

Comment: OK, the problem is definitely that your document is compiled using `latex`, but as you try to include a `.pdf` image, it needs to be compiled with `pdflatex` (or lualatex/xelatex...). So you will have to find out how to select the tex engine in texpad - I unfortunately cannot help you with that. Or you convert `Xwalk.p‌​df` into an .eps file, but I have no idea how one would do this on an ipad...

Comment: I see; I can look into how to do that.  The strange this is that when I compile the file using `texshop` on my computer, I use the `latex` compiler, and it compiles without a problem.

Comment: the manual shows how to set preferences for the engine: https://www.texpad.com/support/osx/typesetting/typesetting

Comment: @naphaneal Thanks, but that is only for the desktop version.  I don't it's possible for the ipad version, unfortunately.